# Using JS CSS to set position causes different outcome than the same setting using pure CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/6e1vg58L/

The javascript adds the "position:fixed" to the nav-content. Everything works how I want, the nav content stays in place while scrolling down the page. Now, if you go and put "position: fixed" under "#nav-content" in the CSS, and delete the JS, it should have the same outcome, correct?

For some reason setting the position in CSS or HTML causes the entire cell to dissapear, while setting it using Javascript or any browser inspector gives it the desired output?

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 0)
    {
        $("#nav-content").css("position","fixed");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#nav-content").css("position","relative");
        $("#nav-content").css("top",0);
    }
});
```

vs

```
#nav-content {
    position: fixed;
}
```

At first I thought it could be something with the listener causing it to work (but why?), but after opening it up in a live browser and adding the "position: fixed" through the inspector, it works exactly how it should. This is the problem, two out of four ways give the same, desired result, but the other two give the same, undesired result.

Comment: Well, actually there are differents one stablish the position at beggining and other set it in an event and/or condition, the real versus would be: `#nav-content { position: fixed; }` vs `$("#nav-content").css("position","fixed");` without anymore, check your jsfiddle and wipe the javascript with on that line and you see the same outcome that you are getting with the css rule.

Comment: I think that your css rules doesn't make what you want. I just delete some useless rules and add a float left. http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/6e1vg58L/2/ The result isn't final but I think this is the right way

Comment: The current CSS is exactly what I want, I left some of the bigger stuff out to isolate the problem, but the setup is designed to be responsive and works at almost any resolution/screen size.

Comment: I think you should read the doc about `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. Maybe it has a specific behaviour with fixed property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am not 100% on the exact whys I think the reason is because by declaring it fixed has the following effect.

> fixed
>   Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position

so it means content being 100% is allowed to take the whole screen when the page is first rendered. Navigation (although not the one being fixed which is the confusing bit) is on the screen but hidden by the content at 100%. the interesting thing is if you use chrome to disable the fixed property the navigation appears and then because it is now on screen reapplying the position fixed does not hide it which is why the JS route behaves differently.

the changes to fix could defining the initial widths in % relative to each other.

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    min-width: 450px;
    height: auto;
}
```

and then the same for navigation

```
#navigation {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vemtyyox/

another way to keep the navigation at 300px could be to use calc to define the width of the content

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    max-width: 1300px;
    min-width: 450px;
    height: auto;
}

#navigation {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9db77jvp/

Looking closer i think there is something odd about the way `display:table-cell` and the fixed properties are working, maybe.

Comment: While you solution does fix the position problem, it completely breaks the responsiveness of the design. I suppose I will have to stick with the JS way of doing it.

Comment: does the use of calc help? if not yeah keep with the js as that way the page is flowed correctly first then the position:fixed can be added.

Comment: Wow, you are awesome! Setting the calc fixed the problem, and the rest of the design stayed responsive! Thanks!

Comment: only thing to look out for is browser support, if you are targeting IE8 there is no support. http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc